# Query for Adding integer data in azure search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is there any provision to receive the searched result fields data summed up as a single integer

For example, if I am searching for 'x' person's bank details and I want the amount he spent using his credit card then the result I need is the sum of all credit card transactions

I couldn't find any documentation.
If we cannot add then what is the best way to approach?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure Search doesn't do any such calculation on the response. However, you can easily implement that on the client side with the response from the service.

Nate

Comment: I am having 900MB of data which returns like 10000 sets for each search.I feel its an ineffective way to do it client side.
And also we can retrieve only 1000 datasets at a time. So you will have to query 10 times to get the whole result data. It defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
BTW I moved to elastic